# Our daughter's foreign passport is stuck on a Home Office application. What are the options if we need to travel soon?

Tags: uk, passports, uk-citizens, greek-citizens

We are about to travel from the UK to Greece on holidays in the next 10 days. 5 ½ months ago we submitted our documentation to the Home Office to register our 2 year old as British citizen which included her Greek passport. We‘ve already submitted 2 official requests for her passport to be returned and also send 2 letter with the request reference numbers to the department dealing with our daughters application. We haven’t heard anything back from them as of today.

Our options are limited and none is really ideal:

1. Withdrawing her application would probably trigger a faster return, however this means a cost of approx. £800.
2. Getting emergency documents from the Greek embassy requires us to declare the passport lost which could potentially also harm the application as it will be triggered as cancelled if they check following cancellation.
3. Getting in direct contact with the Home Office is also not possible until 6 full months have passed.
4. Getting emergency documents from the UK could in theory be possible if the Greek embassy denies to issue a passport, but somehow “We will not issue a passport because you already have one” doesn’t strike me as a valid reason.

Do we have any other options? Till now, the best option I can see is to declare her passport lost and travel on emergency travel documents.

Comment: Your MP may be able to poke the Home Office to work faster, or at least respond to your requets.

Comment: Can you get her a Greek identity card on an expedited basis?  She doesn't need a passport to travel within the EU, after all.

Comment: @phoog AFAIK,she can only get a Greek ID at the age of 12, but I can't verify this. Will try and check with the embassy

Comment: @IoannisDeligiannis Wikipedia says they're *mandatory* for those 12 and older, but that leaves open the possibility that younger people may still have them.

Comment: @phoog I will check with the embassy, however IDs are issued by the police which means it is highly unlikely to be here on time. Should we have known earlier that the documents would be delayed, we would have, but the home office page stated a 10 average and we had more than a month to go

Comment: @AakashM Haven't ever contacted my area's MP. Are you suggesting just sending him an email with all the details and asking him if he can help?

Comment: Have a look at their website to see what their constituency contact arrangements are, they may want a phone call, but basically yes just tell them your problem and they may be able to help (at least with the 'this government department is not resplying to me' bit). You can use http://theyworkforyou.com to find out who your MP is, if you don't know

Comment: @AakashM I have contacted the home office using multiple means and procedures. My MP office was the only one that responded that the issue was resolved and my documents are on the way, so if you move your comment as an answer I'll accept

Comment: @GayotFow may know?

Comment: @pnuts it's no big thing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of an answer, since OP has mentioned *if you move your comment as an answer I'll accept*.

To quote @[AakashM](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3884/aakashm)'s Comment in full:

> Have a look at their website to see what their constituency contact arrangements are, they may want a phone call, but basically yes just tell them your problem and they may be able to help (at least with the 'this government department is not resplying to me' bit). You can use theyworkforyou.com to find out who your MP is, if you don't know

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that this type of requests are actually mentioned on the above website i.e. it's a common request apparently